# ¿Cómo subo mi aplicación jsp en apache tomcat?

Tags: php, html, jsp, mongodb, tomcat

¡Buenas!

Resulta que he terminado mi proyecto en jsp y mi base de datos en mongodb mlab. He investigado al respecto de cómo subir mi aplicación a tomcat... al parecer todo lo he hecho mal desde la instalación de tomcat en mi pc...

Mi aplicación actualmente la tengo en netbeans, le dí el clic derecho y luego en clean and build para crear el .war... pero no se que hacer con eso...

Estoy demasiado perdido....

Por favor, ¿existe alguna manera sencilla y definitiva para montar mi aplicación para que los demás equipos en mi red de trabajo la puedan usar, sin necesidad de tener el netbeans abierto...?

No tengo ni la más remota idea de como hacer esto... ¿Algo paso a paso tipo dummies?

Muchas gracias

Comment: En tomcat un método de instalación de tu War simplemente copialo en $CATALINA_HOME\webapps, tu ip ponla como Estatica para que no cambie y configura tomcat como servicio windows.

Answer (score 1):

En el directorio de instalación del `tomcat` vas a encontrar una carpeta llamada `webapps`. Dentro de dicha carpeta pega el archivo `*.war` que generaste con netbeans.

```
<directorio-instalacion-tomcat>/webapps/
```

Para desplegar la aplicación debes ejecutar el archivo `startup.bat` si usas windows o `startup.sh` si usas linux/mac, este archivo está en:

```
<directorio-instalacion-tomcat>/bin/
```

Una vez que termine de deployar el tomcat, por defecto lo hará en el puerto 8080, por lo que puedes probar en:

```
http://localhost:8080/nombre-de-tu-aplicacion
```

Comment: El puerto se puede configurar? Si es posible... En donde lo configuro? Y solo con el .war es suficiente para ejecutar mi aplicación?

Comment: Puedes editar el archivo `server.xml`, ahí busca el tag `<Connector port="8080"...>` y cambiale al que desees, este archivo esta en `<directorio-instalacion-tomcat>/conf/`. Asegurate que el proceso del tomcat no se este ejecutando, para bajarlo puedes usar el script `shutdown.bat`. Eso debería ser suficiente

Comment: @BrayanRodriguez si esta respuesta solucionó tu duda, por favor considera votarla positivo y marcarla como aceptada.